# Sharing a link on Facebook from a specific website, Facebook suggests liking this website's Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

Try sharing [this link](http://www.mawaly.com/music/Nancy+Ajram/track/9566) (of a music song) on your Facebook wall, after sharing it Facebook will prompt a window suggesting that you like that website's (mawaly.com) Facebook page.

How is this possible?

Here is My Picture :

[image]

Comment: _“How is this possible?”_ – I think Facebook decides whether to display that button. Factors might be popularity of the page, how many of the user’s friends like it, etc.